# JMS onMessage behaviour when JVM process is killed

Tags: java, jms

What happens when I receive some message on onMessage method and, before I finish treatment of the message, the process of my JVM is killed?

The message is redelivered after my process be started again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled specifically by the Acknowledgment portion of JMS. Different JMS providers and clients behave differently.

The message consumer must **acknowledge** the message has been received and processed. The JMS queue will then consider the message to be consumed.

Most providers have an AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE setting which will acknowledge the message after the onMessage() code executes without error.

Answer (score 0):

it is subject to your JMS service provider , in case of weblogic it is written to physical file , that you can re-push again.still it is little complex. location of physical file can configured while creating bridge.

in past we were also facing this issue then we switch  to KAFKA . in KAFKA messages remains on publisher side for some time period, so in case of any crash or issue you can again call publisher.